# Stopping Javascript Function

Tags: javascript, html, function

I would like the JavaScript to stop once the image is clicked. Once the spider gif is clicked, it turns to a splatter.png, but the splatter continues to move around. I am not too fluent with JavaScript to figure it out. If you can help please let me know. Thank you!

```js
var dir_h = 'right';
var dir_v = 'down';

function reset1() {
  clearTimeout(my_time);
  document.getElementById('i1').style.left = "500px";
  document.getElementById('i1').style.top = "100px";
  document.getElementById("msg").innerHTML = "";

}

function disp() {
  var step = 2; // to  Change speed change this step value
  //alert(dir);

  var y = document.getElementById('i1').offsetTop;
  var x = document.getElementById('i1').offsetLeft;
  if (x >= 900) {
    dir_h = 'left';
  }
  if (x <= 400) {
    dir_h = 'right';
  }
  if (dir_h == 'right') {
    x = x + step;
  } else {
    x = x - step;
  }

  if (y >= 500) {
    dir_v = 'up';
  }
  if (y <= 100) {
    dir_v = 'down';
  }

  if (dir_v == 'down') {
    y = y + step;
  } else {
    y = y - step;
  }

  document.getElementById('i1').style.top = y + "px"; // vertical movment
  document.getElementById('i1').style.left = x + "px"; // horizontal  movment

  //////////////////////
}

function timer() {
  disp();
  var y = document.getElementById('i1').offsetTop;
  var x = document.getElementById('i1').offsetLeft;
  document.getElementById("msg").innerHTML = "X: " + x + " Y : " + y
  my_time = setTimeout('timer()', 12);
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <title>Spider Splat Test</title>

  <script src="spider.js"></script>


</head>

<body>
  <img name="myButton" src="spider-animated-1.gif" id='i1' onClick="document.myButton.src='splatter.png';" onClick="document.myButton.src='spider-animated-1.gif';" style="position:absolute; left: 500; top: 100;">

  <br><br><br><br>

  <input type=button onClick=timer() value='Start'>
  <input type=button onClick=reset1() value='Reset'>
  <div id='msg'></div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: you can always exit a method with "return" keywork

Comment: Can you show me a little example? Javascript is not my strong suit.

Comment: Call `reset1()` in the `onclick` function.

Comment: You have 2 `onclick` registered on the same `img`, you can only have one inline attribute event handler per element, so do as @Bamar suggested and combine any functions/statements/expressions in one `onclick`

Comment: Got it functioning properly now. Thank you @zer00ne

Comment: And thank you @Bamar, sorry it wouldn't let me tag 2 people in one comment

Answer (score 0):

Call the reset function in the `onclick` code for the spider.

```
<img name="myButton" src="spider-animated-1.gif" id='i1' onclick="reset1(); document.myButton.src='splatter.png';" style="position:absolute; left: 500; top: 100;">
```

Also, it doesn't make sense to have two `onclick` attributes in the same element.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIU all you need is ajusting onClick on the image:

```js
var dir_h = 'right';
var dir_v = 'down';

function reset1() {
  clearTimeout(my_time);
  document.getElementById('i1').style.left = "500px";
  document.getElementById('i1').style.top = "100px";
  document.getElementById("msg").innerHTML = "";

}

function disp() {
  var step = 1; // to  Change speed change this step value
  //alert(dir);

  var y = document.getElementById('i1').offsetTop;
  var x = document.getElementById('i1').offsetLeft;
  if (x >= 900) {
    dir_h = 'left';
  }
  if (x <= 400) {
    dir_h = 'right';
  }
  if (dir_h == 'right') {
    x = x + step;
  } else {
    x = x - step;
  }

  if (y >= 500) {
    dir_v = 'up';
  }
  if (y <= 100) {
    dir_v = 'down';
  }

  if (dir_v == 'down') {
    y = y + step;
  } else {
    y = y - step;
  }

  document.getElementById('i1').style.top = y + "px"; // vertical movment
  document.getElementById('i1').style.left = x + "px"; // horizontal  movment

  //////////////////////
}

function timer() {
  disp();
  var y = document.getElementById('i1').offsetTop;
  var x = document.getElementById('i1').offsetLeft;
  document.getElementById("msg").innerHTML = "X: " + x + " Y : " + y
  my_time = setTimeout('timer()', 12);
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <title>Spider Splat Test</title>

  <script src="spider.js"></script>


</head>

<body>
  <img onClick=reset1() name="myButton" src="spider-animated-1.gif" id='i1' style="position:absolute; left: 500; top: 100;">

  <br><br><br><br>

  <input type=button onClick=timer() value='Start'>
  <input type=button onClick=reset1() value='Reset'>
  <div id='msg'></div>

</body>

</html>
```

I reduced the speed so our tests are more confortable